# Control Linux from Putty in Windows

Tags: server, ssh, putty, telnet

Is it possible to control a Linux machine (EDIT: like a bash/sudo terminal line) from Putty (or other SSH/Telnet client) that's running off another machine and operating system? I have heard this somewhere before and it seems like a better way to control my server than VNC or RDP; But I cannot find a tutorial online. 
If it is possible, what would be the connection details (or you can just point me to a useful tutorial. 
Thanks in Advance!
Liam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of Linux is you can easily set things up.  It has the original "app store" called a repository.

A repository stores programs that have already been inspected most times by the distro creator and in our case the Debian/Ubuntu community.

It is as easy as installing an ssh server program on your server machine.

The command to install an ssh server is

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

After that you can run Putty, or another Ubuntu machine  to connect simply by using this command.

```
ssh user-name@hostname-or-ip-of-machine-running-ssh-server
```

If you are using Putty just enter the correct details like your username you use on the Ubuntu server and the ip address or hostname.

You should also look into setting up a secret key pair to avoid having to enter your password every time.